# How can I insert select option in Jquery Function

Tags: jquery

I'd like to insert an option in my function where I can choose male or female.

Here is my Function

```
function Add(){
    $("#myTable tbody").append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' maxlength= '2' onkeypress='return(isNumberKey(event));' /></td>"+
        "<td>"WANT TO ADD SELECT OPTION HERE</td>"+
        "<td><input type = 'button' value='Save' class='btnSave'><input type='button' value='Delete' class='btnDelete'/></td>"+
        "</tr>");

    $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);      
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
```

Now the other issue is how to save my selected option in my table and disabling it upon saving and when the edit button is clicked ill be enabled again.

Here's my Save and Edit function

```
function Edit(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdAge = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdGender = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");

    tdName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='"+tdName.html()+"'/>");
    tdAge.html("<input type='text' id='txtage' value='"+tdAge.html()+"'/>");
    tdGender.html(tdGender.html());
    tdButtons.html("<input type='button' value = 'Save' class='btnSave'/><input type='button' value='Delete' class='btnDelete'/>");

    $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
};

function Save(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); 
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdAge = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdGender = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");

    tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdAge.html(tdAge.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdGender.html(tdGender.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdButtons.html("<input type='button' value='Edit' class='btnEdit'/><input type ='button' value='Delete' class='btnDelete'/>");


    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
};
```

Comment: Have you tried doing exactly what you ask - ie adding a select element to your code? Surely this question cannot be serious.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there.

```
$("#myTable tbody").append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' maxlength= '2' onkeypress='return(isNumberKey(event));' /></td>"+
        "<td><select><option value='male'>Male</option><option value='female'>Female</option></select></td>"+
        "<td><input type = 'button' value='Save' class='btnSave'><input type='button' value='Delete' class='btnDelete'/></td>"+
        "</tr>");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried it and it worked. but i do have another issue here. I do need to save the selected value on the select option on my table and after saving it will be disabled

Answer (score 0):

Use radio buttons instead of select for better UI and UX.

```
$("#myTable tbody").append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' maxlength= '2' onkeypress='return(isNumberKey(event));' /></td>"+
        "<td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</td>"+
        "<td><input type = 'button' value='Save' class='btnSave'><input type='button' value='Delete' class='btnDelete'/></td>"+
        "</tr>");
```